# php - Strange Behaviour In date() inside For Loop

Tags: php, date, for-loop

I am trying to show month shorten name using `date()` inside for loop. But it doesn't want to return all of the month names, instead of just the first month name that is `Jan`.

```
    for($d=1; $d<=12; $d++){

    if($d < 10) {
    $s = 0 . $d;
    echo date("M", $s) . '<br/>';
    }

    }
```

It will return:

```
Jan
Jan
Jan
Jan
Jan
Jan
Jan
Jan
Jan
Jan
```

I don't know why the value of variable `$d` won't increment if it is located inside the `date()` function.

Can someone here explain me why it is happened like that?

Best Regards

Comment: Appending '0' to $d is unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($d=1; $d<=12; $d++){
$myDate = mktime(1,1,1,$d,1,2014);
echo date("M", $myDate) . '<br/>';

}
```

This has been tested. Output:

Jan
Feb
Mar
Apr
May
Jun
Jul
Aug
Sep
Oct
Nov
Dec

...

Basically, the second parameter of the date() function needs to be a timestamp (in seconds).

The mktime() function will create a timestamp based on the hours/minutes/seconds/months/days/years that you provide.

https://www.php.net/mktime

Comment: It is the best answer with example. For more flexibility, I changed `1` and `2014`, so it become `mktime(date("H"),date("i"),date("s"),$d, date("j"),date('Y'));`. Thank you for pointing me to that page.

Answer (score 1):

Date() requires timestamp as second parameter, not "month number" as you provide. So, for seconds 1-12 from Unix epoch, month will be January.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the next 12 months from current date this will help you.

```
<?php
for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
    $month = date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$m, 1, date('Y')));
    echo $month. '<br>';
}
?>
```

What you are doing is simply looping current day 12 times and printing the same dates month in each iteration. Thats why you are getting the same month.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
    $month = date('M', strtotime("2014-$m-01"));
    echo $month. '<br>';
}
```